# How do i get a values from fields of a class which implements interface using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm reading all fields values from an object and his children:

```
private List<Object> getAllFieldsValues(Class<?> clazz, String[] filter) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<Object> fieldsValues = new ArrayList<>();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {

        // some code

        if (field.getType().isInterface()) {
            // get all fields from a class which implements the interface
        }
    }
    return fieldsValues;
}
```

I need to get all values from class which implements the interface. How?

EDIT:
My goal is get all fields values to generate some hash:

```
public class HashGen<T extends Layout> {    
    public String hash(T layout, String[] filter) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> current = layout.getClass();

        List<Object> fieldValues = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!current.getName().equals("Object")) {
            fieldValues.addAll(getAllFieldsValues(current, filter));
            current = current.getSuperclass();
        }

        return generateHashFromValues(fieldValues);
    }
}
```

Exemple of my class structure:

```
public interface SomeInterface { }

public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface { 
    private int someField;

    // get / set
}


public interface Layout { }

public interface X540 extends Layout { }

public class X540Impl implements X540 { 
    private int id;
    private SomeInterface;

    // get / set
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    X540 x540 = new X540Impl();
    x540.setId(1);

    SomeInterface someInterface = new SomeClass();
    someInterface.setSomeField(5454);

    x540.setSomeInterface(someInterface);

    // i need to generate an hash of all fields values of X540Impl and SomeClass because X540Impl has a SomeClass
    String hash = new HashGen().hash(x540, new String[] {});

}
```

Comment: Which object? Why are you passing a `Class` and not using the class of the object?

Comment: Well *which* implementation do you want to get the fields from? There could be any number of them. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need to get all values from fields to generate some hash os the values. At the compile time i don't now the type of clazz

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `SomeInterface` is assignable from the type of each field. Something like:

```
if (SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the values of a class with reflection you might want to use the BeanUtils lib from Apache which would save some code writing.

The following example does 2 things that might help

1. It determines if the passed object implements the interface
2. How to get the values from the object using reflection.

   ```
   // obj = the object not the object.class
   if (obj instanceof SomeInterface) {
       for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
           Object value = BeanUtils.getProperty(obj, field.getName());
           System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
       }
   }
   ```